# Using Dwolla Payment Button when account isn't verfied

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, dwolla

It is not clear to me from Dwolla's Payment Button API documentation what `RESPONSE` the user gets in using the Payment Button when their account is not yet verified.

What happens during the 3-5 day purgatory while the user waits on their bank to sync up with Dwolla?

Answer (score 1):

When a user's Dwolla account is pending identity verification (SSN check, photo ID check, etc.) they'll see this error message after logging into the off-site gateway (the payment button redirects the user to our [off-site gateway](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/gateway) to complete the payment)

> Oopsie!
>
> Your account needs further information to complete this order. Please login to Dwolla.com to address this.

The payment will not be completed and the user is left at that error page.

However, if the user has his/her identity verified but has no funding sources (verified bank accounts) and an empty Dwolla balance, upon checking out the user is redirected to the redirect URL that you specified (in the 'href' attribute) with the following querystring data:

```
?error=failure
&error_description=Insufficient+funds+exist+to+complete+the+transaction.
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon, it looks like I need to code a cron job in my app to regularly check for this type of failed transaction such that as soon as money gets in their account, I can try the transaction again using the `transaction/send()` API call